# Creating different colours for different event statuses in a Calendar view

Tags: 2013, calendar

I know that you can use the Calendar overlay to add different colours to a Calendar app. However, I have a calendar view based on a list and would like to have different colours for the different statuses of each event.  Is this possible either through code or some functionality in SharePoint 2013.

Answer (score 0):

Not really, I can only think of the following work-around:

- Include the status of the event in the event's title
- use CSS selectors to change the color

For example, this will change the color of all elements that have a draft status indicated in the title:

```
    [title~="draft"]
    {    
    background-color: red;
    }
```

To use the CSS, preferably don't edit the existing CSS file but use the alternateCSS property or use this guidance: [Customize your SharePoint site UI by using JavaScript](https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP-Guidance/blob/master/articles/Customize-your-SharePoint-site-UI-by-using-JavaScript.md)